# What are the differences between make clean, make clobber, make distclean, make mrproper and make realclean?

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make, packaging, code-cleanup

I don't always write make files but when I do I like to try and write them well.  Trying to make the interface consistent with what other developers might expect is always a struggle.  What I am looking for is a summary of all the common make something cleaner (GNU) make targets.

What are the commonly found cleaning make targets?

When is each target normally used?

How does each target compare to others?

---

I have worked with a system using `make clean`, `make clobber` and `make mrproper` before.  Those got steadily more extream with; `make clean` only tidying up temporaries, `make clobber` getting rid of most configuration and `make mrproper` almost going back to a just checked out state.  Is that the normal order of things?  Should `make mrproper` always remove the generated binaries and shared libraries for deployment?

Reading around suggests that `make distclean` tidies things up to the point of being ready to make a distribution package.  I would imagine that leaves behind some automatically generated version tagging files, file manifests and shared libraries but possibly strips out temporary files that you would not want archived?

`make realclean` was completely new to me when I spied it on the [GNU Make Goals manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html).  As it is listed with `distclean` and `clobber` I would guess it had similar effects. Have I never come across it as it is a historical artifact or just quite specific to a set of projects I have to worked on?

---

Sorry, that is is a bit rambling.  I have found various questions and answers that compare one target to the other but none that seemed to give a good overview.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Trying to form my own answer based on some research.  I think the approximate order of severity is; `mostlyclean`, `clean`, `maintainer-clean`, `mrproper`, `distclean` and finally `clobber` (which is combined `distclean` and `uninstall`).

**make clean**

`make clean` is the most basic level.  It cleans up most generated files but not anything that records configuration.  [GNU Make Manual's Goals page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) states:

> Delete all files that are normally created by running make.

Further, the [GNU Make Manual's Standard Targets page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets) stages:

> Delete all files in the current directory that are normally created by building the program. Also delete files in other directories if they are created by this makefile. However, don’t delete the files that record the configuration. Also preserve files that could be made by building, but normally aren’t because the distribution comes with them. There is no need to delete parent directories that were created with ‘mkdir -p’, since they could have existed anyway.
>
> Delete .dvi files here if they are not part of the distribution.

**make mostlyclean**

`make mostlyclean` is the only gentler form of clean I have found, it behaves like clean but leaves behind files that would take a long time to compile and do not often need to be regenerated.

The [GNU Make Manual's Standard Targets page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets) stages:

> Like ‘clean’, but may refrain from deleting a few files that people normally don’t want to recompile. For example, the ‘mostlyclean’ target for GCC does not delete libgcc.a, because recompiling it is rarely necessary and takes a lot of time.

**make distclean**

`make distclean` is the first step up from the basic `make clean` on many GNU Make systems.  It seems to be pseudonymous or at least very similar to with `make realclean` and `make clobber` in many, but not all cases.  It will delete everything that `make clean` does and remove the configuration.

In the Linux system this is one step beyond `make mrpropper`, see the section below for details.

I am not sure if the name implies that things are being made clean enough for distribution (the forming of a tar archive) or that the process is returning them to the state equal to what was distributed (just as things were immediately after unpacking a tar archive).

[GNU Make Manual's Goals page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) states:

> Any of these targets might be defined to delete more files than ‘clean’ does. For example, this would delete configuration files or links that you would normally create as preparation for compilation, even if the makefile itself cannot create these files.

Further, the [GNU Make Manual's Standard Targets page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets) stages:

> Delete all files in the current directory (or created by this makefile) that are created by configuring or building the program. If you have unpacked the source and built the program without creating any other files, ‘make distclean’ should leave only the files that were in the distribution. However, there is no need to delete parent directories that were created with ‘mkdir -p’, since they could have existed anyway.

**make uninstall**

`make uninstall` will uninstall software installed via `make install` or one of the `install-*` variants.  This is similar to part of the behaviour to `make clobber` on some systems but `make uninstall` should not touch the build area as `make clobber` will.

The [GNU Make Manual's Standard Targets page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets) stages:

> Delete all the installed files—the copies that the ‘install’ and ‘install-*’ targets create.
>
> This rule should not modify the directories where compilation is done, only the directories where files are installed.

**make maintainer-clean**

`make maintainer-clean` seems to be one step back from the more common `make distclean`.  It deletes almost everything apart from the configuration.  This makes it very similar to `make clean`.

The [GNU Make Manual's Standard Targets page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets) stages:

> Delete almost everything that can be reconstructed with this Makefile. This typically includes everything deleted by distclean, plus more: C source files produced by Bison, tags tables, Info files, and so on.

It is also highlighted that this is not a commonly used target as it is for a specific set of users:

> The ‘maintainer-clean’ target is intended to be used by a maintainer of the package, not by ordinary users.

**make mrproper**

`make mrproper` seems to be a Linux Kernel version of `make distclean` or `make clobber`. 
 that stops short of removing backup and patch files.  It does everything that the `make clean` target does and strips out configuration.

I believe the name comes from a cleaning product known in the USA as [Mr. Clean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Clean#International_versions) and the UK as Flash (which is why I had not heard of the product as named).  Linus Torvalds being Finnish-American was presumably familiar with the Mr. Propper brand name.

The [Linux Kernel Makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/94710cac0ef4ee177a63b5227664b38c95bbf703/Makefile#L1268) states:

```
# Cleaning is done on three levels.
# make clean     Delete most generated files
#                Leave enough to build external modules
# make mrproper  Delete the current configuration, and all generated files
# make distclean Remove editor backup files, patch leftover files and the like
```

**make clobber**

`make clobber` gets a mention on the [Wikipedia article for Clobbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering) too.  That also states that it is more severe than `make clean`, possibly one that even uninstalls the software.  It is possible a combination of `make uninstall` and `make distclean`.

---

There is no single source for make clean levels.  As things have evolved over time terminology and behaviour is inconsistent.  The above is the best I have managed to piece together so far.

Comment: IMHO the hope that these escalation steps will speak for themselves or will transport the right information or even dictate the correct usage, is very slim. Look at the Linux Kernel, even this Leviathan of a software project manages to go by only three stages.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I do not expect or suggest that all of them will or should be used at once.  I was trying to work out what common sets of terms were in use and if there was an approximate agreed meaning around them.  `make clean` and `make clobber` make some sense to me but that is only because I have worked on code bases with them before.  The answer to what the difference is, maybe that it is a historical oddity and that people's exposure will vary widely.

Comment: My experience also. For a completely different view on the matter keep in mind that all `clean` commands are just a brutal surrogate for the missing dependency information in a software project. The other half of the dependency info is in the original developers head - or worse, it is nowhere and everybody working on the project grips on a maybe false reliance of these commands.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I would mostly agree but there is a use for `make clean` or similar when preparing either a patch for submission somewhere or generating a clean archive file with no generated content.  Now some strict directory structure could probably replace that and make your point about only being a record of missing dependencies an absolute.

Comment: Great question and brilliant answer. It's shocking - and perhaps telling of the state of Linux in 2019 - that definitive documentation for some of its most common and destructive commands is so hard to come by. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: @Hashim to be fair to Linux the kernel build documentation does document their use of it.  The greater difficulty is that GNU Make was designed as a flexible tool with a few guidelines that suggested people used `make` and `make clean` but little else.  Give thousands of developers 42 years to play around with a system and it is no surprise that some ambiguity creeps in.  TBH I am surprised it is as standardised as it is!